# IIS 7.5 - Deployed WebApp can't access network shared's folder / files

Tags: network-share, iis-7.5, files, web-applications

My project needs to work with some important data and print the results. I'm working with a big DB and few files located on my company's network.  I need to open them, extract data, etc.. But it's not working in production!

Ex : there's "L:\XXXX\YYYYY\FakeNameFile.xls" and when I test my Webapp on local it's working fine but when I deployed it with IIS, it can't open it - File.Exit return false!

I've read a lot of thing on Google but nothing works. Weird thing is when I give the rights to my AppPool in folder's properties I got this :
[image]

And if I do nothing after a few time I got that (I forgot to select the user but it still does have the same rights) :
[image]

Do you have any idea how to let my app having access with IIS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on IIS's forum by lextm.

Mapped drives are not supported by IIS. If you want it to work, have a look [at UNC path](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257174) ! :)

MTEDField